# How to cache websites and HTML5 works offline

Tags: ios, iphone, html, uiwebview

I have an app with `UIWebView` and the visited website is developed in HTML5 so it could work offline.

How I can solve the problem that it works too if there is no connection to the internet? Is it only possible with the manifest file?

Another problem: I want to cache the websites I visited. Does it only works with manifest too?

```
[self setRequestObj:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:loadUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:60.0]];
```

I am using the code above but if I cut the connection to the internet there seems no cached file.

Answer (score 0):

iOS URLLoading system Default caching depends on the HTTP response for the resources in the page. Check the response headers and make sure there is a Cache-Control header with appropriate values in it as they dictate how the default cache on iOS has to behave.

Please refer the below link to understand more about HTTP Caching.
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en

Also, refer to a similar question below:
[How to cache resources loaded by WKWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191088/hot-to-cache-resources-loaded-by-wkwebviewios/37409927#37409927)